# Python liste par compréhension

Tags: python, list

I would like to make my program in list comprehension but I can't do it.

```
n=int(input("Entrer la dimension de la matrice : "))


for i in range(n):
        a=[0]*n
        a[i]=1

        print(a)
```

Comment: Do you have an explicit question to ask ? Can you provide expected versus actual output ? You should visit the [ask] page to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal(to have a matrix where all the elements are zeros except where row and columns indexes are the same there should be ones) this could do the job.

```
n = int(input("Dimension : "))

matrix = [[0 if row != column else 1 for column in range(n)] for row in range(n)]


print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
 [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanx! is that exactly my goal

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand whats the goal of your programm, if you want to initialize a matrix via n from your input you could work with numpy module. See documentation [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/)

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Dimension: "))

array = np.ndarray(shape=(n,n), dtype=int)
array.fill(1)

print(array)
```

Output:

```
Dimension: 2                                                                            
[[1 1]                                                                                  
 [1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly do you want, but I suppose you looking for something like this

```
n = int(input("Entrer la dimension de la matrice : "))
# getting list of lists (empty rows)
M = [[] for _ in range(n)]
# fill each row with another list (columns)
for i in range(n):
    M[i] = [1] * n
# now you can get access to each cell like
print(M[0][2])
```

Also, it's python, you can't make random indentations. Use 4 spaces per indentation level or tab.